# Show that $\frac{x^2}{z}<\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}<\frac{z^2}{x}\implies x<y<x$

Tags: inequality

Question: Show that $\frac{x^2}{z}<\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}<\frac{z^2}{x}\implies x<y<x$?

**My effort:**  We have
$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}<\frac{z^2}{x}$.

$\implies (x^2+y^2+z^2)x<z^2(x+y+z)$.

$\implies x^3-z^3<y(z^2-xy)$......(1),
again
$\frac{x^2}{z}<\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}$.

$\implies x^2(x+y+z) < z(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

$\implies x^3-z^3<y(z^2-xy)$......(2),

(1) and (2) are same. How can I show the result?

Comment: I think that you have a typo in $x<y<x$.

Comment: Assuming that you meant $x\lt y\lt z$ instead of $x\lt y\lt x$, the claim is false. Take $(x,y,z)=(2,1,3)$.